# how to use browserslist with autoprefixer from NPM

Tags: npm, autoprefixer

**Setup**

I have a `package.json` with the following:

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    ...
    "prefix-css": "postcss build/resources/main/css/EverythingDay.css --use autoprefixer -b \"last 1 chrome versions\" -o build/resources/main/css/EverythingDay_prefixed.css",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
    "autoprefixer": "^6.7.7",
    "postcss-cli": "^3.2.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    "last 1 chrome versions"
  ],
  ...
```

**What I want**

I want to use postcss's autoprefixer plugin on my main css file, and I want it to take a `browserslist` into account. It seems to be the default list of browsers.

As I understand it, you should add a `browserslist` entry to your `package.json`, so that multiple tools (like autoprefixer and babel) can take it into account.

**The problem / question**

The css file do get prefixed, but it `autoprefixer` doesn't use the browser list. Neither from the `-b` nor the `"browserslist"`.

What am I doing wrong? I would prefer the `"browserslist"` solution, as that seems to be the "right" way

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue where `postcss-cli` wouldn't pick up a custom browserslist config. I tried command line parameter `--autoprefixer.browsers`, a `browserslist` section in `package.json`, but nothing was getting picked up.

I found this approach after spending a good hour down the rabbit hole of `postcss`, `postcss-cli` and `autoprefixer` docs. It is based on `postcss-6.0.13` with `autoprefixer-7.1.5`. Not sure if it applies to your situation with different package versions and all, but here goes:

- Add a config file to your project with config values for your post css plugins:

**postcss.config.js**

```
module.exports = {
    plugins: {
        autoprefixer: { 
            browsers: [
                "ie 10",
                "> 1%"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

- Tell `postcss` to use this config file through the --config parameter (and nothing else):

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
    "prefix-css": "postcss --config postcss.config.js -o style.css",
}
```

At first I had the `--use autoprefixer` still in the command together with the config. Maybe that was throwing it off back to the defaults. This way it seems to work and it enables me to hide away the postcss config complexity nicely :-).

Hope it helps someone!